# Refrigerator in garage was turned off

Tags: food-safety

We just realized that our garage refrigerator/freezer was not on. The eggs are still cold to the touch but the vegetables, rice w/shrimp and meatballs in the freezer are not frozen but still cold. The ice cream is mostly melted. This tells us that the frig hasn't been off for a long time but we don't know for how long. Should we throww all the frozen foods away? Or would it be safe to cook everything instead.

Comment: You'll get a much better answer if you can take actual temperature measurements from the inside of the refrigerator and freezer.

Comment: If the eggs float in water, they probably should be tossed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the frozen goods are a lost cause. Throw them away. The eggs in the fridge are probably fine. Break one in a dish and give it the sniff test. If it still smells clean and good, they are probably fine. But don't delay in using them. Make a souffle!